# How is 学习紧张和劳动并不矛盾 the answer to 那位中学生家长展示的特别简历说明……？

Tags: meaning

This is from Chapter 1 from the HSK6 Standard Course workbook ([photo of original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19eqr.jpg); OCRed via [Yandex](https://translate.yandex.com/ocr?)):

> 曾几何时，《劳动最光荣》的儿歌响彻大江南北，影响了一代又一代人。对于 35 岁以
> 上的绝大多数人而言，他们还是孩子的时候，勤劳致富、劳动光荣等传统美德就深深地
> 扎根在他们的心里了。
>
> 可现在的一些孩子，同他们讲热爱劳动、勤劳致富，他们会认为这些都过时了。一
> 位小学三年级学生的妈妈说，三年级以前我还会让孩子自己洗洗袜子，后来作业多了，
> 就不让孩子洗了，也基本不让她参与家务劳动。实际情况是，劳动在家庭教育里日渐缺
> 失。是否需要补齐、如何补齐劳动这一课，是不少家长所困惑的。
>
> 一位品学兼优的中学生的家长却向记者展示了一
> 份特别的简历——她女儿的"日常考核表"。这份考核
> 表中包括劳动、礼貌等指标。家长说："从幼儿园开始，
> 我们就要求孩子逐渐学会自理，参与家庭劳动，在她上
> 小学时就带她参加植树活动、去养老院打扫卫生等。"
> 可见学习任务重，不是孩子舍弃劳动的理由。
>
> 有教师认为，家庭中的劳动教育需要家长用心设
> 计。家长要根据孩子的身体状况、时间状况制订劳动计
> 划，并和孩子一起体验;还可以设计一些创意性劳动，让孩子参与其中，享受由此带来
> 的成就感。事实证明，转变家长对孩子参与劳动的观念，使家长先意识到劳动在孩子学
> 习、生活和未来长远发展中的积极意义，是改变孩子不热爱劳动现状的根本办法。
>
> 35. 那位中学生家长展示的特别简历说明：
>     A **学习紧张和劳动并不矛盾**
>     B 爱劳动的孩子也会有礼貌
>     C 春天很多孩子都愿意去种树
>     D 劳动习惯是在幼儿园养成的

Question 35 relates to the content in the 3rd paragraph.  The given answer is A, without further explanation.  I confidently chose D because it says:

> 从幼儿园开始，我们就要求孩子 ... 参与家庭劳动

I've now realized that D is incorrect because answer D says 在幼儿园 instead of 从幼儿园开始.  However, I'm still baffled as to how A could be correct.  The text doesn't use the word 紧张.  I'm starting to think there's a meaning of 紧张 other than "nervous", and the text has somewhere used a synonym of it.

**Question**: How is 学习紧张和劳动并不矛盾 the answer to 那位中学生家长展示的特别简历说明……？

Answer (score 2):

I think A is more the default winner, because the others are not applicable.

B 春天很多孩子都愿意去种树
B reference: 在她上 小学时就带她参加植树活动
during primary school we took her to participate in tree-planting activities
春天 not mentioned

C 爱劳动的孩子也会有礼貌
kids who love work may also have good manners (also may not!)
C reference: 是改变孩子不热爱劳动现状的根本办法。
is a basic way of changing children's negative attitude towards work
C not mentioned

D 劳动习惯是在幼儿园养成的
work habit is cultivated in kindergarten
D reference: 从幼儿园开始， 我们就要求孩子逐渐学会自理，参与家庭劳动，
since kindergarten we gradually required her to learn self-sufficiency, and help with housework

A 学习紧张和劳动并不矛盾
learning stress and work are not contradictory
A reference: 可见学习任务重，不是孩子舍弃劳动的理由。
We can see (can we really?) a heavy study load is not a reason for a child to stop participating in chores.

Answer (score 2):

The 3rd paragraph is concluded by "可见学习任务重，不是孩子舍弃劳动的理由" (The heavy workload of learning tasks is not a reason for children to abandon labor).

Answer A: 学习紧张和劳动并不矛盾 (Pressing learning tasks do not conflict with labor) essentially says the same thing.

> I'm starting to think there's a meaning of 紧张 other than "nervous"

You're absolutely right. 紧张 here means "pressing".

我很紧张。 I'm nervous.

工作很紧张。 The work is pressing.

Answer (score 1):

> 劳动在家庭教育里日渐缺失。是否需要补齐、如何补齐劳动这一课，是不少家长所困惑的。

The focus of the discussion is "Should doing work be included in home education?"

> 一位品学兼优的中学生的家长却向记者展示了一 份特别的简历——她女儿的"日常考核表"。这份考核 表中包括劳动、礼貌等指标

The report on an excellent student indicated that 'work' is a part of a complete education. Therefore, there is no conflict between work and study.

> 从幼儿园开始，我们就要求孩子 ... 参与家庭劳动

The child was required to work, but that doesn't mean she would develop the habit of working hard (many people work reluctantly because everyone needs to make a living)

Answer (score 1):

- 一位**品学兼优**的中学生的家长却向记者展示了一 份**特别的简历**——她女儿的"日常考核表"。这份考核 表中**包括劳动**、... 可见**学习任务重，不是孩子舍弃劳动的理由**.

Through the opening and the ending sentences, this student's parent is using the student's excellent academic status (品学兼优) and daily activity record as proof that "劳动" does not conflict with "学习", as shown by the live example.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the paragraph "一位品学兼优...", the keyword **可见** (**The conclusion is that**) provides the answer to you. **可见学习任务重, 不是孩子舍弃劳动的理由**, which is exactly the option A **学习紧张和劳动并不矛盾**.

If only read that, 家长说: "从**幼儿园**开始, 我们就要求孩子逐渐学会自理, 参与家庭劳动, 在她上小学时就带她参加植树活动, 去养老院打扫卫生等. ", then you may choose the option D "劳动习惯是在**幼儿园**养成的". The parent did not mention **学习** at all. Therefore it seems that option A "学习紧张和劳动并不矛盾" can not be the correct answer. But this is just one of the supporting facts, not the whole meaning of the paragraph. In the very beginning of the paragraph, the report said that the student is "品学兼优" (the student is excellent in study and performance).

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a close look at paragraph 3.

1 一位品学兼优的中学生的家长却向记者展示了一 份特别的简历——她女儿的"日常考核表"。
2 这份考核 表中包括劳动、礼貌等指标。
3 家长说："从幼儿园开始， 我们就要求孩子逐渐学会自理，参与家庭劳动，在她上 小学时就带她参加植树活动、去养老院打扫卫生等。"
4 可见学习任务重，不是孩子舍弃劳动的理由。

The 1st sentence3 leads in the special resume. The 2nd sentence shows more details. The 3rd sentence talks about all requirements.  The 4th sentence is the conclusion.

"包括劳动、礼貌等指标", at least 劳动 and 礼貌 are included. "从幼儿园开始" not "在幼儿园"。So D is wrong.

Normally the core sentence is at the beginning or in the end of a paragraph. And he correct answer should be A